# Django append domain name after localhost

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I created a django project. when i start server and open 127.0.0.1:8000/admin. I redirect to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.pxxx-xxxx.com/order/success/admin/
```

then django show error "

> Page Not Found(404)

why django append url (www.pxxx-xxxx.com/order/success/) after 127.0.0.1:8000.

This are my current settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))),
        ".."
    )
)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contact',
    'festival',
    'uploads',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_name.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_name.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['DBNAME'],
        'PASSWORD' : os.environ['DBPASS'],
        'USER' : os.environ['DBUSER'],
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DBHOST', None)
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.environ['STATIC_ROOT']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ['MEDIA_ROOT']

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And this is how my urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('website.urls', namespace='website')),
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give the url.py ? and also settings.py?

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: add route to the func def @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST']) def webhook():

Comment: I posted my settings.py and urls.py. Please check

Comment: Open a incognito window in chrome and then try

Comment: Same issue in incognito window